# Can you please explain what the information in this stock quote means?

Tags: investing, stocks, starting-out-investing, quotes

I'm trying to understand shares as of "now", so I know more or less nothing about them.  I have discovered this website:  http://www.google.com/finance?q=microsoft

I entered in microsoft and it comes up with

- Company name:
  Microsoft
- Price
  27.72
- Change
  +0.39
- Chg %
  1.43%
- Mkt Cap
  232.18B

At the top of the page, it says "Currency in USD".

So what do those figures mean?

Does it mean 1 share of Microsoft is currently valued at $27.72 USD as of Jul 29, 7:03AM EDT?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that's what it means. Also, it tells you that the share price went up by $0.39 yesterday, which was an increase of 1.43% from the previous day's price, and that the total value of all of Microsoft's shares is $232.18 billion (from which we can deduce that there are a bit less than 10 billion Microsoft shares in total).